# Vector space of polynomials?

Tags: calculus

I am studying for an exam and one of the past questions was:

Determine if these are vector spaces:

$1)$ The set of polynomials divisible by $x² + x + 1$;

$2)$ The set of differentiable functions with repect to $x$ on $[0,2]$ whose derivative is $3x²$.

For question 1 I'd say it is a vector space as the polynomial contained the zero vector and is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. Is this correct?

For the second question I am confused about what the question is actually asking. I know I have to again test the vector space axioms but can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct for the first.

The second cannot be a vector space:  Consider $f(x) = x^3$.  Certainly $f(x)$ is a member of our vector space.  Well, $f(x) + f(x) = 2x^3$, and $\frac{d}{dx}(2x^3) = 6x^2$.  Therefore, it is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your reasoning for the first to attack the second. Since the derivative of $0$ is not $3x^2$, so the space has no $0$ element and cant be a vector space.